# Is there a method for statistical comparison performed within for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a series of numerical vectors containing multiple values.

```
hc_mcp = [0.45, 0.43, 0.46, 0.46, 0.45, 0.39, 0.48, 0.47, 0.50, 0.45, 0.47, 0.47, 0.46]
hc_pct = [0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.37, 0.56, 0.46, 0.49, 0.53, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48]
hc_gcc = [0.51, 0.56, 0.57, 0.54, 0.55, 0.58, 0.51, 0.54, 0.55, 0.54, 0.55, 0.53, 0.54]
hc_bcc = [0.56, 0.62, 0.64, 0.63, 0.60, 0.65, 0.60, 0.64, 0.64, 0.61, 0.63, 0.58, 0.63]
hc_scc = [0.68, 0.73, 0.74, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.71, 0.67, 0.73]

tw_mcp = [0.47, 0.46, 0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.44, 0.47, 0.46, 0.50, 0.49, 0.48]
tw_pct = [0.46, 0.48, 0.45, 0.48, 0.47, 0.45, 0.46, 0.43, 0.43, 0.49, 0.49, 0.47, 0.44]
tw_gcc = [0.56, 0.56, 0.55, 0.57, 0.52, 0.56, 0.53, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.55, 0.56]
tw_bcc = [0.62, 0.63, 0.60, 0.63, 0.61, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.61, 0.65]
tw_scc = [0.71, 0.70, 0.70, 0.71, 0.68, 0.74, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71]
```

I need to calculate Wilcoxon sign-ranked test for each couple of vectors (hc_mcp-tw_mcp, hc_pct-tw_pct...). Because the couples of vectors have a similar name, is it possible to design a for loop in which I recall them? I would like to avoid something like this due to the number of vectors (48 per group, 3, in total 144):

```
res = wilcoxon(hc_mcp, tw_mcp)
p = res.pvalue

res = wilcoxon(hc_pct, tw_pct)
p = res.pvalue
```

I imagined a for loop similar to the following:

```
for rois in roi_jhu:
res = wilcoxon(ri_%s, hc_%s) %(rois)
p = res.pvalue
ri_hc_pvals.append(p)
```

I know it is wrong, but the idea would be this.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You have three groups of vectors. For each of them, the first two characters indicate the group they belong to ("hc", "tw" and some third combination), and the characters after the "_" are the same "list" for each group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of your groups of vectors and then loop through them. You just have to take care that the "vector couples" are in the same position in their respective list:

```
hc_mcp = [0.45, 0.43, 0.46, 0.46, 0.45, 0.39, 0.48, 0.47, 0.50, 0.45, 0.47, 0.47, 0.46]
hc_pct = [0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.37, 0.56, 0.46, 0.49, 0.53, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48]
hc_gcc = [0.51, 0.56, 0.57, 0.54, 0.55, 0.58, 0.51, 0.54, 0.55, 0.54, 0.55, 0.53, 0.54]
hc_bcc = [0.56, 0.62, 0.64, 0.63, 0.60, 0.65, 0.60, 0.64, 0.64, 0.61, 0.63, 0.58, 0.63]
hc_scc = [0.68, 0.73, 0.74, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.71, 0.67, 0.73]

tw_mcp = [0.47, 0.46, 0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.44, 0.47, 0.46, 0.50, 0.49, 0.48]
tw_pct = [0.46, 0.48, 0.45, 0.48, 0.47, 0.45, 0.46, 0.43, 0.43, 0.49, 0.49, 0.47, 0.44]
tw_gcc = [0.56, 0.56, 0.55, 0.57, 0.52, 0.56, 0.53, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.55, 0.56]
tw_bcc = [0.62, 0.63, 0.60, 0.63, 0.61, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.61, 0.65]
tw_scc = [0.71, 0.70, 0.70, 0.71, 0.68, 0.74, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71]

#if they are sorted by name, you could do this
list1 = [hc_mcp, hc_pct, hc_gcc, hc_bcc, hc_scc]
list2 = [tw_mcp, tw_pct, tw_gcc, tw_bcc, tw_scc]

ri_hc_pvals = []

for ind in range(len(list1)):
    res = wilcoxon(list1[ind], list2[ind])
    ri_hc_pvals.append(res.pvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using plain python lists, a popular option nowadays would be to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) [DataFrames](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to store the information as 2-dimensional tables. Of course another alternative would be dictionaries of lists.

Here's how you create a pandas DataFrame from your data (ideally you would read it from excel or csv file, for example with [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
  hc_mcp = [0.45, 0.43, 0.46, 0.46, 0.45, 0.39, 0.48, 0.47, 0.50, 0.45, 0.47, 0.47, 0.46],
  hc_pct = [0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.37, 0.56, 0.46, 0.49, 0.53, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48],
  hc_gcc = [0.51, 0.56, 0.57, 0.54, 0.55, 0.58, 0.51, 0.54, 0.55, 0.54, 0.55, 0.53, 0.54],
  hc_bcc = [0.56, 0.62, 0.64, 0.63, 0.60, 0.65, 0.60, 0.64, 0.64, 0.61, 0.63, 0.58, 0.63],
  hc_scc = [0.68, 0.73, 0.74, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.71, 0.67, 0.73],
  tw_mcp = [0.47, 0.46, 0.44, 0.48, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.44, 0.47, 0.46, 0.50, 0.49, 0.48],
  tw_pct = [0.46, 0.48, 0.45, 0.48, 0.47, 0.45, 0.46, 0.43, 0.43, 0.49, 0.49, 0.47, 0.44],
  tw_gcc = [0.56, 0.56, 0.55, 0.57, 0.52, 0.56, 0.53, 0.55, 0.55, 0.55, 0.56, 0.55, 0.56],
  tw_bcc = [0.62, 0.63, 0.60, 0.63, 0.61, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.63, 0.62, 0.63, 0.61, 0.65],
  tw_scc = [0.71, 0.70, 0.70, 0.71, 0.68, 0.74, 0.72, 0.73, 0.70, 0.68, 0.69, 0.70, 0.71],
))
```

Now it is fairly easy to loop over the columns. For example, like this:

```py
roi_jhu = ['mcp', 'pct', 'gcc', 'bcc', 'scc']
ri_hc_pvals = dict()

for roi in roi_jhu:
   hc = df[f'hc_{roi}'].to_numpy()
   tw = df[f'tw_{roi}'].to_numpy()
   res = wilcoxon(hc, tw)
   ri_hc_pvals[roi] = res.pvalue
```

which could produce something like this:

```py
>>> ri_hc_pvals
{'mcp': 0.3480984832707553,
 'pct': 0.9665707012105913,
 'gcc': 0.8203356580770992,
 'bcc': 0.3076647387703212,
 'scc': 0.25786196569562403}
```

If you have many collections is p-values or other metrics, you might find it easier to have a dictionaries inside a dictionary for the results.

Comment: Yes, I know Pandas and in general I use it when I have to manage data stored in .csv file. However, in this instance I do not have the original file where data are stored and I just reported variables in a Python script. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion! :D